# Implement more conditions on upsert (user defined table types) in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, user-defined-types

I've a table named 'VendorItemPricing' in my database. I'll insert/update data into this table periodically using Data Table, in other words bulk insert/update operation I'll perform.

Below is my stored procedure to perform this operation, and it works good.

Assume this is my table ***VendorItemPricing***:

```
ItemPartNumber  VendorName  VendorPrice UpdatedDate                 ObsoleteItem    IsLocked
Z0PD            Apple       1177        2015-05-27 11:11:14.700     0               0
C1GM            Apple       181.25      2015-05-27 11:11:14.700     0               1
```

Whenever I send a datatable to my stored procedure it'll check the condition.

Assume this is my input:

```
ItemPartNumber => Z0PD
VendorName => Apple
```

Now, it check with the condition.

```
tableVendor.ItemPartNumber = 'Z0PD' and tableVendor.VendorName = 'Apple' and tableVendor.IsLocked = 0
```

The first item will get updated since it satisfied the given condition.

Now assume this is my input:

```
ItemPartNumber => ZWEPD
VendorName => Apple
```

Now, it again check with the condition.

```
tableVendor.ItemPartNumber = 'ZWEPD' and tableVendor.VendorName = 'Apple' and tableVendor.IsLocked = 0
```

The new row will be inserted since the input data isn't matching with the condition. This's also great.

But in this type of input,

```
ItemPartNumber => C1GM
VendorName => Apple
```

When it check with the condition.

```
tableVendor.ItemPartNumber = 'C1GM' and tableVendor.VendorName = 'Apple' and tableVendor.IsLocked = 0
```

The condition is now false, and the query is inserting the new row. :(

It shouldn't insert the row, since there's a data with this part number. If Item with IsLocked = 1, it should not get neither updated nor inserted.

I hope I explained my situation clearly. Can anyone help me in fixing this error?

This is my stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WP_InsertUpdateVendorItemPrices]
    @inputTable InsertUpdateVendorPrices READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE INTO VendorItemPricing tableVendor
    USING @inputTable tableTemp
    ON tableVendor.ItemPartNumber = tableTemp.ItemPartNumber and tableVendor.VendorName = tableTemp.VendorName and tableVendor.IsLocked = 0 
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET tableVendor.VendorPrice = tableTemp.VendorPrice, tableVendor.UpdatedDate = GETUTCDATE(), tableVendor.ObsoleteItem = 0
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT VALUES(tableTemp.ItemPartNumber, tableTemp.VendorName, tableTemp.VendorPrice, GETUTCDATE(), 0, 0); 
END
```

Comment: What is the expected behavior when a row is locked?  For example, you could (1) silently ignore the record, (2) stop the whole update with an error message to the user, (3) import anyway and report error message back to the user.  Each of these would be handled in a slightly different fashion.

Comment: Expected behavior is one which is silently ignore the record.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Myself got an answer. Thanks everyone.

This is the latest updated working stored procedure.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[WP_InsertUpdateVendorItemPrices]
      @inputTable InsertUpdateVendorPrices READONLY
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    MERGE INTO VendorItemPricing tableVendor
    USING @inputTable tableTemp
    ON tableVendor.ItemPartNumber = tableTemp.ItemPartNumber and tableVendor.VendorName = tableTemp.VendorName
    WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET 
        tableVendor.VendorPrice = CASE WHEN tableVendor.IsLocked = 0 THEN tableTemp.VendorPrice ELSE tableVendor.VendorPrice END,
        tableVendor.UpdatedDate = CASE WHEN tableVendor.IsLocked = 0 THEN GETUTCDATE() ELSE tableVendor.UpdatedDate END,
        tableVendor.ObsoleteItem = CASE WHEN tableVendor.IsLocked = 0 THEN 0 ELSE tableVendor.ObsoleteItem END
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
    INSERT VALUES(tableTemp.ItemPartNumber, tableTemp.[VendorName], tableTemp.[VendorPrice], GETUTCDATE(), 0, 0); 
END
```